# Convert List to Map of Map

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have an object array like below.

```
[
    {
        "defName": "Project",
        "defDesc": "Project 1",
        "defID": "abcd123",
        "defClass": "class1"
    },
    {
        "defName": "Project",
        "defDesc": "Project 2",
        "defID": "asdoihw1345",
        "defClass": "class2"
    },
    {
        "defName": "Project",
        "defDesc": "Project 3",
        "defID": "ewrwu123",
        "defClass": "class3"
    },
    {
        "defName": "Product",
        "defDesc": "Product 1",
        "defID": "pgkorejgoi1234",
        "defClass": "class1"
    },
    {
        "defName": "Product",
        "defDesc": "Product 2",
        "defID": "asadsad2343",
        "defClass": "class2"
    },
    {
        "defName": "Product",
        "defDesc": "Product 3",
        "defID": "4dgaksld",
        "defClass": "class3"
    }
]
```

I have converted into a `List<Defintion>`. Now I'm trying to convert to into a `Map<String, Map<String, Defintion>` where the first map key is the `defName` and the second map key will be the `defDesc`. It is confirmed that `defDesc` will be unique for specific `defName`.

Currently I'm doing in the following way.

```
List<Definition> definitions = // Got from JSON
Map<String, List<Definition>> definitionByName = definitions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Definition::getDefName));
Map<String, Map<String, Definition>> definitionMap = new HashMap<>();
definitionByName.forEach((name, definitionList) -> {
    Map<String, Definition> definitionDescMap = definitionList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(def -> def.getDefDesc(), Function.identity()));
    definitionMap.put(name, definitionDescMap);
});
```

Can we do it in Single statement? I'm using Java 8 now. Java 8 and new versions solutions are welcome for future references.

Comment: So is it working but you are looking for a different solution (better? faster? clearer? more maintainable?, cleverer? ) What is the problem you want to solve? If anything I would make it easier to read and maintain (granted performance doesn't deteriorate) and then work on something else.

Comment: If you find yourself nesting collections, 9/10 times it's a sign that you really want a class to represent that data. E.g. a `Map<String, Category>` for sorting into `"Product"` vs `"Project"`, and then `Category` in turn may hold a `Map<String, Definition>` for describing ID/class of various things under a `Category`.

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, Definition>> definitionByName = definitionList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Definition::getDefName, Collectors.toMap(Definition::getDefDesc,Function.identity())));`

Comment: Please edit your code to show the list in a compilable form. Not something that looks like toString() output.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute all the items for a given definition name in a single loop, because you're using maps after all.

If the entry exits you add a new map with the description. If it doesn't you create a new map and add it.

You can even leverage `Map.computeIfAbsent(k, func)` to have it in one expression:

(If you really want it in one line)

```
definitions.forEach( d -> map.computeIfAbsent( d.name(), k -> new HashMap<String,Definition>()).put(d.desc(), d));
```

Here's a full example with output (Java 17)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    var definitions = List.of(
          new Definition("project", "project 1", "id1", "class1"),
          new Definition("project", "project 2", "id2", "class2"),
          new Definition("project", "project 3", "id3", "class3"),
          new Definition("product", "product 1", "id4", "class1"),
          new Definition("product", "product 2", "id5", "class2"),
          new Definition("product", "product 3", "id6", "class3")
        );
    var map = new HashMap<String,Map<String,Definition>>();
    
    // Properly formatted 
    definitions.forEach( d -> 
        map.computeIfAbsent(
          d.name(), k -> new HashMap<String,Definition>()
        )
        .put(d.desc(), d)
    );

    System.out.println(map);
  }
}

record Definition(String name, String desc, String id, String type){}


/*
 
Output (formatted): 

{
  product={
    product 3=Definition[name=product, desc=product 3, id=id6, type=class3], 
    product 1=Definition[name=product, desc=product 1, id=id4, type=class1], 
    product 2=Definition[name=product, desc=product 2, id=id5, type=class2]
   }, 
   project={
      project 2=Definition[name=project, desc=project 2, id=id2, type=class2], 
      project 1=Definition[name=project, desc=project 1, id=id1, type=class1], 
      project 3=Definition[name=project, desc=project 3, id=id3, type=class3]
   }
}

*/
```

Comment: There is a difference between the @iCode's output and this one. From this below code only a single Project is coming under Project key `Project={Project 3=Definition [defName=Project, defDesc=Project 3, defID=ewrwu123, defClass=class3]}` but from the @iCode's code the output is like `Project={Project 3=Definition [defName=Project, defDesc=Project 3, defID=ewrwu123, defClass=class3], Project 1=Definition [defName=Project, defDesc=Project 1, defID=abcd123, defClass=class1], Project 2=Definition [defName=Project, defDesc=Project 2, defID=asdoihw1345, defClass=class2]}`

Comment: That's what I don't quite understand:  _"It is confirmed that `defDesc` will be unique for specific `defName`"_ I thought that meant 1:1 relationship between name and description, but it seems more of a collection of 1:M where 1 name can appear in multiple descriptions. Thank you for point it out @ArunSudhakaran

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran updated based on your comment.